# Discord Bot JS interaction reply does not wait until the code finish executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I just started to code and trying to build a discord js bot. I am scraping data from a website. My problem is that the `await interaction.reply(randomFact);` will execute immediately while my code have not finish scraping and return the result. I have tried async/await but still does not work.

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("tips")
        .setDescription("Scrap from website"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        let randomFact;
        let healthArray = [];
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("https://www.example.com/health-facts/"); 

            const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return {
                    html: document.documentElement.innerHTML,
                };
            });

            const $ = cheerio.load(pageData.html);

            $(".round-number")
                .find("h3")
                .each(function (i, el) {
                    let row = $(el).text().replace(/(\s+)/g, " ");
                    row = $(el)
                        .text()
                        .replace(/[0-9]+. /g, "")
                        .trim();
                    healthArray.push(row);
                });

            await browser.close();

            randomFact =
                healthArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * healthArray.length)];
        await interaction.reply(randomFact);
    },
};
```

[the output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPvgC.png)

Sorry if there is anything lacking in my post. I just joined stack overflow.

Comment: I have removed the real website URL due to privacy.

Comment: You want to await for the code that is before that function, not await for that function. Try adding `await` before `(async () => {`

Comment: After I did that, I get this error: `DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction` and `The application did not respond` on discord server.

Comment: That is another issue not related to this question really. Probably `randomFact` contains some unexpected value.  Try using `console.log(randomFact)` and see what you get.

Comment: randomFact has the value that I wanted though. It did console log the value.

Comment: Why don't you move `await interaction.reply(randomFact)` inside that IIFE. Actually, why do you have an IIFE there? `execute` is already an async function.

Comment: After I moved it and removed the another async function I am still getting error of `DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction`. The thing is, the program reads the `await interaction.reply(randomFact)` first instead it should only execute that code after done with the scraping.

Comment: Please show how the code looks right now.

Comment: I have updated the code above with error output img. @KonradLinkowski

Comment: The program doesn't read the `await interaction.reply(randomFact)` first. You have to had some discord API related problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discord api has a timelimit of 3 seconds to reply to a interaction before it expires, to increase this timelimit you will need to use the `deferReply` method found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply), the attached link is for the ButtonInteraction but the SelectMenueInteraction and other types of interactions also have the same method so shouldn't be a issue
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?query=Interaction.defer